# Return Distinct row in resultset in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to select the distinct row if the particular column have same record multiple times in sql server 2008 and order by datetime.
I have following column in table:

1. id
2. username
3. fileid
4. datetime

I have try using following sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(fileid) FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[TableName] where usernumber = '015578957'
```

How can I select other column in above sql and order by datetime column and also return result set row where fileid column is distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select T.*
FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[TableName] T
JOIN
(
SELECT min(id) id, fileid
FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[TableName] 
group by fileid
)X ON T.id=X.id
where T.usernumber = '015578957'
```

If you want to select first distinct record use MIN as in above query and if you want to retrieve the last one use MAX instead of MIN.